# tomcat url domain rewrite

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

I have an application that lives on tomcat without apache fronting it and as our company has grown and changed we have cnamed multiple domains to this application.  So now www.mydomain.com www.yourdomain.com www.ourdomain.com all resolve to the same host.  I now need to only support one, but maintain bookmarks and links that may be out there. so:

www.mydomain.com/stuff/more/pickle  rewrites the url to www.mynewdomain.com/stuff/more/pickle

I assumed at first I could use the UrlRewriteFilter found here http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/  but it seems to be dealing with the uri and not the domains.